# How do I save unknown dying plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I received an unknown plant for Christmas and since repotting it in my room, it has been dying. My best guess is that it is a spider plant (but see photo for more information). At first it was in a semi-lit space (no direct sunlight), but once I saw that the leaves were turning brown I moved it into my kitchen which has south facing windows (so direct sunlight). The leaves are now drooping quite a bit and even more leaves are turning brown. I have tried watering more/watering it less and everything I do seems to make it worse.
Any ideas what I can do to save my plant? 
[image: Picture of my dying plant]

Answer (score 2):

Your plant is in a bit of a state so its hard to be certain quite what it is,  but I think its *Dracaena sanderiana*, not a spider plant - this plant is often sold as 'lucky bamboo', when it looks like a collection of thin canes with maybe one or two leaves, but it can be grown as a foliage houseplant.

It will not appreciate direct sunlight - indirect bright light is best. It prefers humid air, so don't  stand near a heat source, and mist occasionally. Water only when the surface of the potting soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry its shrunken from the sides of the pot. Water well, and allow the excess to drain away freely - empty out the outer pot or tray 30 minutes after watering so it is not left sitting water.

Despite its sad appearance, the plant is not yet entirely dead, so follow the advice given here and perhaps it will start to grow more healthily. The conditions described are also suitable for a Spider plant, so as it regenerates, it will be easier to give a certain ID.

Further information here, please be sure to click the 'Care'  tab for care instructions  https://www.primrose.co.uk/-p-130504.html?cPath=4561_14437?option=8804&gclid=CjwKCAjwguzzBRBiEiwAgU0FTw1aBt8kwXeBsGiIyejPTPJcRLJV2ru1lM_mPHfWJGWvM696_fR5VhoCsAYQAvD_BwE